# Image source missing while generating HTML elements dynamically in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have 4 rows in DataTable dt5. I am trying to generate certain html elements dynamically equal to number of times as the rows in dt5.
Visual studio code:

```
<% for(int i = 0; i < dt5.Rows.Count; i++)
{
%>
<div id="Div1"  class="image_stack" style="margin-left:600px" runat="server" >
<img  class="stackphotos photo1" src="~/Images/3.jpg" clientidmode="static" runat="server" />
<img  class="stackphotos photo2" src="~/Images/4.jpg" clientidmode="static" runat="server"/>
<img   class="stackphotos photo3" src="~/Images/5.jpg" clientidmode="static" runat="server"/>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<% } %>
```

I am able to generate the html but the problem is  the desired html i.e (view source in mozilla) should be....
First Iteration code:

```
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Div1" class="image_stack" style="margin-left:600px">
<img src="Images/3.jpg" class="stackphotos photo1" />
<img src="Images/4.jpg" class="stackphotos photo2" />
<img src="Images/5.jpg" class="stackphotos photo3" />
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

but the result i am getting is (browser view source) ...

```
<div id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Div1" class="image_stack" style="margin-left:600px">
<img class="stackphotos photo1" />
<img class="stackphotos photo2" />
<img class="stackphotos photo3" />
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><<br /><br />
```

As you can see the 'src' part is missing in the code generated .WHy is src missing?

OK, it seems to be working now thanks to Code Rider. 
now i am trying to get the src from datatable.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dt5.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
       string   a = dt5.Rows[0]["imageurl"].ToString();
       string b = dt5.Rows[1]["imageurl"].ToString();
       string c = dt5.Rows[2]["imageurl"].ToString();
  %> 
   <div id="Div1"  class="image_stack" style="margin-left:600px" runat="server" >
    <img id="Img1"  class="stackphotos photo1" src="<%a%>"   />
    <img id="Img2"  class="stackphotos photo2" src="<%b%>"  />
      <img id="Img3"   class="stackphotos photo3" src="<%c%>" />
 </div>
     <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <% } %>
```

Comment: Run the page in IE and check the source of the page.

Comment: @Saurabh tried on IE , still not working.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to generate runat=server controls there. Actually they're not so "~" won't be resolved.

Comment: @Adriano i removed ~ it still did not work , i removed runat="server" and ~ both , it did not work. I tried putting ~ but removeing runat="server" it too did not work!

Comment: @Adriano it seems my code is working fine in the first iteration but it refuses to work after first iteration. Do you want to see more of the generated html code?

Comment: You still have duplicated ID. You should make them unique using index or remove them.

Comment: @Adriano I was using Id for testing something. I will remove it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tried this with below code. Its working fine here.

```
      <% for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
  %> 
   <div id="Div1"  class="image_stack" style="margin-left:600px" runat="server" >
    <img id="Img1"  class="stackphotos photo1" src="11.png"   />
    <img id="Img2"  class="stackphotos photo2" src="11.png"  />
      <img id="Img3"   class="stackphotos photo3" src="11.png" />
 </div>
     <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  <% } %>
```

Comment: your code is working :) i have already voted +1. I will mark it as answer too , but can you please help me get the 'src' from datatable in the above code? 

I have edited my question.

Comment: yes sure. It should go as an another question. I know what you are asking. post an another question. i'll give you answer.

Comment: please mark it as answer. it will help others in future. and post a new question for another query. I'll give you answer there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718052/how-can-pass-datatable-values-in-a-loop-in-aspx

Answer (score 0):

can you tried with below code..

```
<% for(int i = 0; i < dt5.Rows.Count; i++)
{
%>
<div id="Div1"  class="image_stack" style="margin-left:600px" runat="server" >
<img  class="stackphotos photo1" src="Images/3.jpg" clientidmode="static" runat="server" />
<img  class="stackphotos photo2" src="Images/4.jpg" clientidmode="static" runat="server"/>
<img   class="stackphotos photo3" src="Images/5.jpg" clientidmode="static" runat="server"/>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<% } %>
```

Means just remove ~ sign before image url..

Comment: i removed ~ it still did not work , i removed runat="server" and ~ both , it did not work. I tried putting ~ but removeing runat="server" it too did not work!

Comment: it seems that my code is working fine for the first iteration but refuses to work in iterations after first one.

Comment: yes but now i am able to display the images but i want to get teh src from datatable, i have edited my question. Please see if you can help?