# How to pass DataTable values in a loop in aspx?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a DataTable called dt5 which has 4 rows. I am trying to pass the src of image in aspx from dt5, but its not working. Here is my code...

```
<%
    for (int i = 0; i < dt5.Rows.Count; i++)
         {
           string   a = dt5.Rows[0]["imageurl"].ToString();
           string b = dt5.Rows[1]["imageurl"].ToString();
           string c = dt5.Rows[2]["imageurl"].ToString();
      %> 
       <div id="Div1"  class="image_stack" style="margin-left:600px" runat="server" >
        <img id="Img1"  class="stackphotos photo1" src="<%a%>"   />
        <img id="Img2"  class="stackphotos photo2" src="<%b%>"  />
          <img id="Img3"   class="stackphotos photo3" src="<%c%>" />
     </div>
         <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
      <% } %>
```

Comment: is it giving any error? or changes are not reflecting? whats happening on page?

Comment: better formatting is useful to get replied.

Comment: what is the point of the loop if you do dt5.Rows[0] and give number

Comment: try src='<%a%>' instead of double quotes use single quotes.

Comment: @btevfik loop is to generate code as many times as there are albums in database and each album displays the top 3 images in a fancy preview (jquery)

Comment: @CodeRider the code is not working. There are numerous errors in the code.

Comment: @CodeRider replaced it with '<%a%>'. Still not working.

Comment: look at here i think your formatting is wrong http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: for loop needs to be in <%

Comment: @btevfik for loop is withing <% %> , i missed it while copy pasting it here. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

didn't you forget ( : ) ?  if it gives any error then

it should be written in this way:

```
<%: a %>
```

Comment: How does it feel getting your post marked as answer when its just 6 characters long? :D

Comment: it's my pleasure. sometimes this kind of problems is hard to guess. or it takes time. but that problem happened to me long time ago that's why i remembered it... good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variables a,b,c as `public string a,b,c;` in your code behind before use that variables in html

Comment: Did that, still same problem. I guess a,b,c are not in the scope since i am not able to find them in intellisense .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the code you have posted above. But at my end i have tried and find a solution. I created a test application and it works for me. please try:

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
       {
           string a = "11.png";
           a = "11.png";
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           sb.Append("<div id='Div1' class='image_stack' style='margin-left: 600px' runat='server'>");
           sb.Append("<img id='Img1' class='stackphotos photo1' src='" + a + "'/>");
           sb.Append("  </div>");
    %>
    <% Response.Write( sb.ToString()); %>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <% } %>
```